# printing output of google geomap as image using R

Tags: r, google-maps, rgooglemaps

I am using googlevis package to plot a geographic map. The output I get is HTML. Is it possible to generate jpg or png output?

Comment: If you're using Google Maps this is against the Terms of Service (which do not allow creating a derivative work). The correct way getting a jpeg or PNG image is via the Static Maps API.

Comment: thank you Andrew i will try google static map

Comment: As a terrible hack you could make a screenshot...

Answer (score 1):

Following Andrew tip I suggest to take a look at the [RgoogleMaps](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RgoogleMaps/index.html) package. It seems to provide what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the [osmar](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmar/) package which uses the data from OpenStreetMap.